# Sublime Text 2 How To Change Default Runtime Shell Command For C++?

Tags: c++, sublimetext2

I'm trying to run a c++ program through sublime text 2. I do not want to add bash to my PATH.
 I want to change the default cmd command to the following:

```
./${file}
```

I looked all around in the c++ packages folder but only found the build.

I appreciate some help!

[EDIT]
My program builds correctly, but upon runtime I get this:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'bash', u'-c', u"g++ 'C:...]
[dir:  C:\Users\...]
[path: C:/.../
[Finished]
```

[EDIT] As per requested, my build file.

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please include your `C++.sublime_build` file.

Comment: It is the default build file.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["${file_path}/${file_base_name}"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Just drop the compilation command and retain only the executable invocation part. But remember, you have to compile before running otherwise the executable would not have got generated.